# Is it true that the last season of OreGairu skipped many important scenes from the novel, giving a biased view towards Yui?

Tags: oregairu

I've come across quite a few comments from Light Novel readers who were very upset with the 3rd season of the anime because it apparently skipped a lot of the story, especially important scenes with Yukino, resulting in a very biased view towards Yui.

As someone who only watched the anime, it did seem to me that Yukino became a bit bland and out of focus for pretty much the whole season until the 2nd half of episode 11.
So, I'd like to ask, are these accusations true? If yes, which important scenes with Yukino did the 3rd season of the anime skip?